# Share variable between two services with two different client call

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to share a variable between two services when calling two client proxies.
(And also variable should be shared per session) My sample code as below,

** Server **

Service 1

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string SharedValue = string.Empty;

    public void SETValue(string inputString)
    {
        SharedValue = inputString;
    }
}

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SETValue(string inputString);
}
```

Service 2

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService2 : MyService, IMyService2
{
    public string GETSharedValue()
    {
        return base.SharedValue;   //This value got Empty
    }
}

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMyService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GETSharedValue();
}
```

I'm using 'wsHttpBinding' for both services.

** Client **

```
    private string sharedValue = string.Empty;
    MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient client = null;
    MyService2Reference.MyService2Client client2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        client = new MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient();
        client2 = new MyService2Reference.MyService2Client();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.SETValue("Hello this is client 1");

        sharedValue = client2.GETSharedValue();
        lblResult.Text = sharedValue;
    }
```

Comment: WCF Session is usually per service. Does it need to be non-persistent? Do you have any auth or any way to know what "session" the value actually belongs to? Can you tie it to a userId or something?

Comment: You can take a look at InstanceContextSharing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354514.aspx

Comment: I instantiate clients object only once. No I'm not using any auth currently.Is there any method to find auth? Thanks for the reply.I ll check your link.

Answer (score 0):

write a class with a static variable
eg:

```
public static class  SharedValues

    { 
       public static String SharedValue = string.Empty;
    }
```

then use

```
 public void SETValue(string inputString)
    {
        SharedValues.SharedValue = inputString;
    }
```

if you want concurrency cosider using a lock statement

Comment: Wouldn't that string be available for other sessions as well?

Comment: I tried static variable, that will share with all the sessions like a global variable.

Comment: @smoksnes    Shamilrox sorry i have misunderstood the question,  i think one way to do it is InstanceContextSharing smoksnes said, but i have not tried it yet, another way to it is create a session id on client side (caller)  pass it with the function and maintain a static key value dicionary server side

Comment: @Priyan-R The problem is I have implemented integration service app that is tightly coupled.

Comment: Did u check check instancecontextsharing